# How do I read multiple integers from a line of input in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, python-2.x, multiple-input

I am new to python. I searched and found out how to do it in python 3:

```
v = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

but in python 2 I get the syntax error. I need it for foobar because I can't code in c++ nor python 3 there which is incredibly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2 you have 2 input functions:

- `raw_input` : this does what you expect; it reads the input as a string.
- `input` : this actually evaluates the user input; this is why you get a syntax error; you cannot evaluate a string like `"1 2 3 4 5"`.

So you want to use `raw_input()`:

```
v = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
```

In Python 3 `input` instead does what you want.

Comment: @HaaaatzJhonule I didn't know that... It sucks.... Anyway the solution I proposed works on python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
v = [int(x) for x in raw_input("Enter your numbers separated by space: ").split()]
```

#### In Python 2.X

- `raw_input()` takes exactly what the user typed and passes it back as a string
- `input()` first takes the `raw_input()` and then performs an `eval()` on  as well.

#### In Python 3.X

- `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` so now `input()` returns exactly what the user typed and passes it back as a string
- Old `input()` was removed.

Answer (score 0):

In python3 there is no `raw_input`. The python3 `input` is the renamed python2 `raw_input`. So in python2 you should use `raw_input` instead. Like this:

```
v = [int(x) for x in raw_input("Enter numbers here").split(" ")]
```

The argument in `split` is the separator. In the first example the separator is a space. But if you want to get the numbers separated with `-`, you can use it like this:

```
v = [int(x) for x in raw_input("Enter numbers here").split("-")]
```